# SVG + CSS3 bug, multiple browsers?

Tags: html, css, webkit, svg, gecko

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/5fLtb/3/

When you hover over it in webkit browsers (Chrome/Safari), it seems to glitch and go light blue then to the proper colour.

In Gecko browsers (Firefox), it doesn't fade in at all.

Could someone tell me if this is a bug or if there's a way around it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bit silly to load a whole new svg image when all you really need to do is to change the color of it.

For something this small you could just use inline svg, see e.g http://jsfiddle.net/zuWGy/1/.